# Way of executing another method while video is being recorded?

Tags: android, task, video-recording

I'm using `MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE` to allow video recording. While the video is recording I'd like to execute another method. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: Any boolean method I can call to figure out if the user has started recording yet?

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use`service` or`asyntask.`  If you decide that you must do many background work (and in serialize), `asyntask` is more benefit.

Comment: Yes but this doesn't detect when the user has clicked the record button. I want to start this background task as soon as its started recording.